Can parametricity be applied to show a property of function values?
Say I have the following dictionary of abstract operations, written in Haskell for relatively concise notation:
data Dict d = MkDict
  { fun   :: (d -> d) -> d
  , apply :: d -> d -> d
  , stuff :: (d -> d -> d) -> d -> d }

Now I want to exploit parametricity at a Haskell function f :: forall d. Dict d -> d -> d. In the semi-formal style of Wadler, the abstraction theorem gives me:
$$
  (f, f) ∈ \forall \mathcal{X}.\ \mathsf{Dict(\mathcal{X})} \to \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}
$$
(where the type formers here are interpreted relationally.)
The relational interpretation of this fact amounts to
\begin{align*}
  &\forall A, B.\
  \forall R ⊆ A \times B.\
  \forall (\mathit{inst_1}, \mathit{inst_2}) ∈ \mathsf{Dict(R)}.\
  \forall (d_1,d_2) ∈ R.\\
  &(f_A(\mathit{inst_1})(d_1), f_B(\mathit{inst_2})(d_2)) ∈ R
\end{align*}
My goal is to instantiate this theorem so that I can prove a property about a concrete, fixed implementation of $\mathit{inst} : \mathsf{Dict}(D)$ for some fixed $D$, on which I also define a partial order $(\sqsubseteq) \subseteq D \times D$.
The property in question is
$$
  \forall (f:\forall X.\ \mathsf{Dict(\mathit{X})} \to X \to X)\ (a:D)\ldotp f_D(\mathit{inst})(a) \sqsubseteq \mathit{inst.\!apply}(\mathit{inst.\!fun}(f_D(\mathit{inst}))(a)
$$
How do I formulate for this property of functions $D \to D$ a matching relation $R \subseteq D \times D$, so that it instantiates the abstraction theorem to show the property?

I think I found a solution to my problem.
But it is a bit unfair to previous answers, because they were lacking context.
Specifically, I knew how fun is implemented. For my idea to work, it is important to know that fun f can only call f a finite number of times, and that we can enumerate all the call sites.
In my specific case, there was just a single call $f(\mathit{pre})$ (where $f$ is the semantic function corresponding to f) inside the implementation of fun with a special $pre : D$ that is not parametric (note that the implementation of fun knows how $D$ is defined and can do all kinds of shenanigans).
Now I can instantiate the abstraction theorem from the Q as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c}
  A \triangleq B := D, \qquad \mathit{inst_1} := \mathit{inst_2} := \mathit{inst}, \qquad d_1 := a, \qquad d_2 := \mathit{pre} \\
  R_{a}(d_1,d_2) := \forall g.\ d_1 = g(a) \land d_2 = g(\mathit{pre}) \implies g(a) ⊑ \mathit{apply}(\mathit{fun}(g),a)  \\
\end{array}$$
FWIW, $R_{a}$ can be further simplified once $\mathit{fun}$ is inlined; then the strange quantification over $g$ vanishes and I get $R_{a}(d_1,d_2) = d_1 \sqsubseteq \mathit{apply}(\mathit{abs}(d_2),a)$ for some $\mathit{abs}$ with the property $\mathit{fun}(f) = \mathit{abs}(f(\mathit{pre}))$.
Instantiating the abstraction theorem and simplifying it a bit yields
$$\begin{array}{l}
a ⊑ \mathit{apply}(\mathit{fun}(\mathit{id}),a) \land (\mathit{inst}, \mathit{inst}) ∈ \mathsf{Dict}(R_{a}) \implies \\
  f_D(\mathit{inst})(a) ⊑ \mathit{apply}(\mathit{fun}(f_D(\mathit{inst})),a)
\end{array}$$
And I could successfully prove the premises to show the desired property.

This approach can be generalised to implementations of fun that call f more than once, simply anticipating all potential arguments $\mathit{pre}_1, ... \mathit{pre}_n$ and then generalising $R$ to type $D \times D^n$.

Perhaps someone has an idea to make this simpler?

That's a strange R because d2 is not used in the conclusion, and d1 can also be rid of by substitution, that's just "for all f, f a ⊑ app (fun f) a". And if you have that, you don't need parametricity since you can apply that property directly to f.

I think the premises are important because it enlarges R. Proof: I don't think your substitution rewrite is reversible in general. That's important because otherwise it's exactly what you say: "If you have that, you don't need parametricity".

The premise filters out fs that I cannot do the proof for. R says that "any f is fine, as long as it coincides with all the points I specify", because that gives me enough leverage to prove the inequality.

I updated a bit and used the more familiar style from Wadler to derive the free theorem. Still same $R$, but I explain a bit how it simplifies once fun inlines.

Does your solution still require some knowledge about the structure of all possible terms of type Dict d -> d -> d? That's what it looks like to me. In my answer, I derived the structure of all possible terms of a simpler type. Perhaps you need to generalize that technique to a more complicated type where both fun and apply from inst are used.

I'm not sure I understand your question. Of course I require "knowledge about the structure of all possible terms of type Dict d -> d -> d", that's exactly the knowledge provided by parametricity! Perhaps I should have said so, but without appealing to parametricity, I cannot prove the property f a <= apply (fun f) a; I can find a counter-example for f. Crucially, this counter-example is not parametric, that is, not definable at type forall d. Dict d -> d -> d!


f(a) ⊑ inst.apply(inst.fun(f),a)

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, that's not a property that holds for all functions f of that type.
Counterexample:

f = \inst x -> inst.fun (\_ -> x)
D = Bool with the discrete order (x ⊑ y iff x == y)
inst.fun = \_ -> False
inst.apply = \_ _ -> True.


Right, I said "fixed, but arbitrary set D with the partial order (⊑)⊆D×D,", and that's actually wrong. $D$, the ordering and the dictionary is fixed, but not arbitrary.
The property of interest definitely holds (I can prove it without parametricity). It seems I just need to state it properly.

I updated the question. I don't really want to detail how $D$ and $⊑$ is defined; but parametricity should not need that either.

Let me reformulate your question via code.
You want to obtain some parametricity property for functions of this type:   $$   \forall d.~ (\textrm{Dict}~ d) \to d \to d $$
Since you are only interested in using the fun property of Dict, let me drop other properties of Dict and define a simpler type $U$ as:
$$ U = \forall d.~ ((d \to d) \to d) \to  d \to d  $$
Note a similar question posted here: Can we use relational parametricity to simplify the type $\forall a. ( (a \to a) \to a ) \to a$? where the type was $$T = \forall a.~((a\to a)\to a)\to a$$ The type $U$ differs slightly from the type $T$ in that question. My answer to that question can be suitably modified to show that $U$ is equivalent to the following type:
$$ U \cong \forall r. \mu b. \mathbb1 + r + (r \to b) $$
and to derive an explicit form of type $U$:
$$ U \cong  (\mathbb1 + \mathbb1) + (\mathbb1 + \mathbb2) + (\mathbb1 + \mathbb3) + ...$$
Values of this type are pairs of integers $m, n$ where $m \geq n + 1$ and $n \geq 0$.
I omit the details of the derivation. Please look through the detailed proof shown in my answer to the question linked above.
A term corresponding to each alternative of this union type can be written explicitly. The general form of terms of type $U = \forall d. ~((d\to d)\to d)\to d \to d$ can be written as one of $u_{m,n}$ (with $m\geq n\geq 1$) or $u_m$ (with $m\geq 1$) or $u_0$:
$$ u_{m,n} = \lambda p^{~: (d\to d)\to d}.\,\lambda q^ {~: d}.~  p(\lambda r_1.\,p(\lambda r_2.\,...\,p(\lambda r_m.\,r_n)...) $$
$$ u_m = \lambda p^{~: (d\to d)\to d}.\,\lambda q^{ ~: d}.~  p(\lambda r_1.\,p(\lambda r_2.\,...\,p(\lambda r_m.\,q)...) $$
$$ u_0 = \lambda p^{~: (d\to d)\to d}.\,\lambda q^{ ~: d}.~  q $$
Parametricity assures that there are no other terms of type $U$.

But I'm also using $\mathit{apply} : d \to d \to d$, so it's more like $U=∀d. ((d→d)→d)→(d→d→d)→d→d$, a very different type. Plus, other operations in $d$ really use methods like $\mathit{stuff}$, so I want to know how to prove them correct as well

@SebastianGraf Indeed that would be a very different type, much more complicated. In any case, I was just trying to translate your question into a language that is close to programming. The way you formulate your question, I can't make any sense of it. Where does your notation come from, what book or paper? For example, I have no idea what  ⟦ ⊦  ⟧$~_$( $$;$$) means, as I have never seen such notation before.

Oh, I thought that notation would be standard, apologies. It's from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106611500078X?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=899d0885af262c10.

FWIW, I rewrote the Q so that it uses the more familiar and scrutible, but slightly informal notation from Wadler.
